# why ngspice gives no relevant output?

Tags: lubuntu

when i run the following circuit via ngspice(Lubuntu 18.04),

```
circuit
V 0 1  DC 10
R 0 1 5
.end
```

it outputs this:

```
Circuit: circuit


ngspice 1 ->
```

"print all" leads to this:

```
Circuit: circuit


ngspice 1 -> print all
false = 0.000000e+00
true = 1.000000e+00
boltz = 1.380620e-23
c = 2.997925e+08
e = 2.718282e+00
echarge = 1.602190e-19
i = 0.000000e+00,1.000000e+00
kelvin = -2.73150e+02
no = 0.000000e+00
pi = 3.141593e+00
planck = 6.626200e-34
yes = 1.000000e+00
```

Why is there no circuit-specific output?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no circuit-specific output because you haven't simulated anything yet.

The most basic simulation you can do is `op`, which performs a DC operating point analysis:

```
$ ngspice test.cir
******
** ngspice-27 : Circuit level simulation program
** The U. C. Berkeley CAD Group
** Copyright 1985-1994, Regents of the University of California.
** Please get your ngspice manual from http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/docs.html
** Please file your bug-reports at http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/bugrep.html
** Creation Date: Tue Dec 26 17:10:20 UTC 2017
******

Circuit: circuit

ngspice 1 -> op
Doing analysis at TEMP = 27.000000 and TNOM = 27.000000



No. of Data Rows : 1
ngspice 1 -> print all
v(1) = -1.00000e+01
v#branch = -2.00000e+00
ngspice 1 ->
```

Comment: Alright, thank you my friend. I was following the description from the book "DC.pdf" by Tony R. Kuphaldt(last update 2006). He used the windows version 2g.6 of SPICE and in my opinion it provides a way better organized output including "total power dissipation"(page 68) even without the "op-simulation-step".  I guess there is no way to emulate that behaviour in ngspice. Anyway the main-problem ist solved.